# Netflix Karyon not using Governator to create resources classes

Tags: java, jersey, guice, netflix

I'm playing with Karyon and I've hitting a problem where Jersey and not Governator is trying to instantiate my rest resource classes. I'm trying to do a more robust than the hello world example where I can specify my own Guice modules for injection.

If I use the @InjectParam annotation Jersey finds it and says I missing a mapping for the constructor. If I only use the @Inject annotation then Jersey, not Guice, complains that I can't inject the constructor.

I found this thread, https://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/users/archive/2011-01/message/102, that exactly describes the problem I'm having but using another aspect of Jersey. I'm not sure what the equivalent problem class in Karyon is. Has anyone else had this problem when creating their own modules?

Begining of the Rest Resource

```
@Path("/")
public class CrudRoot {

  private final CrudService service;

  @Inject
  public CrudRoot(CrudService service) {
    super();
    this.service = service;
```

My module

```
protected void configure() {
    bind(CrudService.class).to(InMemCrudService.class);
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee ">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>KaryonCrud</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.example.karyon.server</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>KaryonCrud</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/v1/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.karyon.server.CrudServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This post has moved to the karyon-users Google Group. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/karyon-users/RM2IIVGNKXI

Comment: A solution was found within the Google Group. A full example can be found here https://github.com/PatrickAuld/KaryonCrud.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points here:

1. You must specify com.netflix.karyon.server.guice.KaryonGuiceContextListener as a servlet context listener. I am not sure, the listener you specified in your example extends this class or not.
2. In order to use jersey with guice you have to use a [JerseyServletModule](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9.1/contribs/jersey-guice/com/sun/jersey/guice/JerseyServletModule.html). Karyon's example does not demonstrate this as of now, it should.

Comment: I was extending the KaryonGuiceContextListener to set the Archaius app and env properties originally, I'm now setting them with the Tomcat setenv.sh and using the original listener.

I've been though the Karyon examples and they don't have examples of using custom modules. From the documentation it seems custom modules should be set in the ServerBootstrap.beforeInjectorCreation() method, is this correct? 

When I use the JerseyServletModule (I was using the Guice Servlet before) the Guice listener is complaining that it can't find any root resource classes. This might be my bad conf somewhere.